# Rails + carrierwave not creating conditional versions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, carrierwave

I'm trying to set up conditional versions with carrierwave in my Rails app. I've implemented what seems to be an exact duplicate of the examples provided [here](https://github.com/jnicklas/carrierwave).

The version is never created though unless my `is_ipod?` simply returns `true`. The code below is what I currently have and is not working. Notice the commented sections I've used to verify the `image_type` attribute is actually set correctly.

```
version :ipod_portrait_thumb, :if => :is_ipod? do

  process resize_to_fit: [150,200]

end

def is_ipod? image
  model.image_type == 'iPod Screenshot'

  #if (model.image_type == "iPod Screenshot")
  #if (model.image_type!=nil)
    #puts "+++++"+model.image_type
  #  if (model.image_type=="iPod Screenshot")
      #puts "+++++++ I AM HERE"
  #   return true
  #  end
  #end
end
```

If `is_ipod?` looks like this:

```
def is_ipod? image
  true
end
```

the version is created as expected. What am I missing? Thanks!

**UPDATE:**

I've edited the `is_ipod?` method to look like this:

```
def is_ipod? image     
  puts (image.path || "") + ': ' + ((model.image_type||"") == 'iPod Screenshot').to_s
  model.image_type == 'iPod Screenshot'
end
```

Which outputs this to the console:

```
/public/uploads/tmp/20130325-1024-15906-5363/drawing.png: false
/public/uploads/tmp/20130325-1024-15906-5363/drawing.png: false
/public/uploads/app_image/image/59/drawing.png: true
```

So the version is trying to be created three times, twice for temp files and once for the final file. The model attribute is only set for the final file. Is this related? Can anyone tell me how this is different than this example?

```
class MyUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base

  version :monkey, :if => :is_monkey?

  protected

  def is_monkey? picture
    model.favorite_food == 'banana'
  end
end
```

Here is my model class in case that helps:

```
class AppImage < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :app_id, :image, :image_type, :image_cache
  belongs_to :app

  mount_uploader :image, AppImageUploader

  validates :image_type, presence: true
  validates :image, presence: true
end
```

Thanks!

Comment: That might sounds like the stupid question but are you 100% sure that when you're doing your tests, the model.image_type is equal to 'iPod Screenshot' ? With the correct case ? Cause it really looks like the condition `model.image_type == 'iPod Screenshot'` is never met, hence your version never created

Comment: I am sure. Notice the commented out explicit tests putting "I AM HERE" to the console. I have verified this happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out this is happening because the `AppImage` model is a child of another model and is being added here on a nested form. For whatever reason child models don't have their attributes set by the time carrierwave processes versions.

I've verified this by adding carrierwave attachments to my parent model `App`. When the versions are processed for an `App` attachment, the attributes are set.

Maybe later I'll dig deeper to try and understand better (I'm pretty new to Rails), but for now I'm working around the issue by not having conditional versions.

Comment: Have you found any solution! 
Paperclip has the same issue, conditional resize manipulated when updating , but at the time of creation, it just do not work.

Comment: hey have you resolved this issue... I too have the same issue with my nested forms .. I am unable to fix this issue .. if you did solve this issue can you please let me know ... please ...

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem^ and I tried to create different sizes depending on model attribute. My solution is simple: just recreate versions after save.

app/uploaders/project_item_picture_uploader.rb

```
class ProjectItemPictureUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base

  ...

  version :preview do
    process dynamic_process: true
  end

  protected

  def dynamic_process(*args)
    resize_to_fill *(model.get_size) if model.persisted?
  end

end
```

app/model/project_item.rb

```
class ProjectItem < ActiveRecord::Base
  mount_uploader :picture, ProjectItemPictureUploader
  validates_presence_of :picture

  def get_size
    double ? [168, 57] : [76, 57]
  end

  after_save :recreate_delayed_versions!
  def recreate_delayed_versions!
    picture.recreate_versions!
  end
end
```

Comment: This is a good solution! But only works the image is about to be resized to something smaller. FYI for anyone reading

Answer (score 1):

I have the same issue this night and i'm doing some experimentation with it, finally i figured out, it seem that when your create a version for the first time (when you post your form), if you have this line :

```
model.image_type == 'iPod Screenshot'
```

this means that you should **obligatory** have a field in your form named `image_type` and the value for this field should be "iPod Screenshot"

CarrierWave verify the same thing when you show your image like `article.image_url(:ipod_portrait_thumb)` which means that you should have in your database a field named `image_type` with value "iPod Screenshot"

so if you have this line :

```
version :ipod_portrait_thumb, :if => :is_ipod?
```

you are telling CarrierWave to execute ipod_portrait_thumb function each time you **Create or Show** a record

in Case that your form don't contains the `field image_type` with value 'iPod Screenshot', for example because you set it in your model/controller, the way is to check another field to permit CarrierWave create your conditional version, so it's simple you can do something like this :

```
model.image_type == 'iPod Screenshot' || another_field_in_my_form_help_you_to_know_type_is_ipode == "something" # or just .present? rather than == "something" switch your case
```

here when CarrierWave try to create version the first time it will check this another_field_...... , and when you have a page that show your record (product, article....) it verify `model.image_type == 'iPod Screenshot'` that is stored already in your database

Hope this help you :)